# Logging DML operations in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, cdc, aspect

In a asp.net mvc project, there are various ways to logging dml operations like insert, update, delete. I wonder which one is useful using aspects in code or using triggers or CDC in database server or are there more logical ways?

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few ways.

Assuming you're using Entity Framework as your ORM, you could register an application interceptor (see [IDbCommandInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbcommandinterceptor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)). See [Logging and intercepting database operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) for more info...

Another approach, which is quite handy to log ALL database operations is to set the `Database.Log` property on your DbContext implementation as follows:

```cs
public class YourContext : DbContext
{   
    public YourContext(ILogger<YourContext> logger)
    {
        Database.Log = sql => logger.LogDebug(sql);
    }
}
```

^^ I found this approach to be quite useful for debugging. I would have a file appender/target/sink (depending on what logging framework you're using e.g. NLog/Log4net/Serilog) specifically for my DbContext implementation, so that I could easily see the SQL of the database operations that are being executed without any noise from other application logs.

The other approach that I've used quite a bit is to use SQL Server Profiler, but this assumes a) you're using SQL Server, and b) you're able to connect to the database server.